# Image uploading API Call works properly with Postman but why not working with Android App ?

Tags: php, android, api, retrofit2, multipart

I am trying to upload an image through API call from my app. But it seems to me that it is working in postman but not when done through my app. I am using retrofit 2 and backend code is PHP.Kindly help me through the process.

PHP Code:

```
case 'profileImage':

$id=$_POST['id'];
$image_name=("profile".$id.".jpg");
$upload_path=("../gm-app/assets/images/users-profile/".$image_name);

    $res= mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE `users` SET `image` = ('$image_name') WHERE `userid`='".$_POST['id']."'");

    if(isset($_FILES['file'])){

         if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_path)){

            $rs['message'] = "Profile Image Updated";
            $rs['stat'] = "SUCCESS"; 
    }else{

        $rs['message'] = "Profile Image not Updated";
        $rs['stat'] = "FAILED";

    }
    }

echo json_encode($rs);die;
    break;
```

Retrofit call:

```
File file = new File(mediaPath);
        RequestBody requestBody=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
        Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().
                baseUrl(MyConstants.ROOT_URL).
                addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).
                build();

        apinterface services = retrofit.create(apinterface.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call=services.postImage(requestBody,uid);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.body()!=null)
                {

                    try {

                        Toast.makeText(MyProfile.this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String image =  response.body().string();

                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+image);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

API :

```
@Multipart
    @POST("services.php?apicall=profileImage")
    Call<ResponseBody> postImage(@Part("file") RequestBody image, @Part("id") String id);
```

Comment: do you get an exception or an error response from the server?

Comment: @SripadRaj Nope. Nothing. While debugging the process just loops out from the 'call.enqueue' part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there's something wrong with your code about multipart..

**Interface** :

```
@Multipart
@POST("services.php?apicall=profileImage")
Call<ResponseBody> postImage(
    @Part MultipartBody.Part image, 
    @Part("id") RequestBody id
);
```

**Call the API**

```
Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().
        baseUrl(MyConstants.ROOT_URL).
        addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).
        build();
apinterface services = retrofit.create(apinterface.class);

//Bikin request body
File file = new File(mediaPath);
RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), reqFile);
RequestBody reqId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), uid);

//Tembak APInya
services.postImage(reqfile, reqId)
    .enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            //tulis aksi disini
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            //tulis aksi disini
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the post method like this.

```
@Multipart
@POST(Urls.POST_A_QUERY)
Call<CommonResponseModel> postAQuery(@Part("treatmentDetails") RequestBody treatmentDetails,@Part MultipartBody.Part file1);
```

Then

```
 File file = new File(filePath);
 RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mediaType), file);
 document1 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("report1", Utils.getEdittextData(edtFirstFileName).concat(".jpg"), requestFile);
```

Then pass that document1 value in second parameter.

```
 String mediaType = getActivity().getContentResolver().getType(uri);
            if (mediaType == null) {
                mediaType = Utils.getMimeType(filePath);
            }
```

Get mimetype function.

```
 public static String getMimeType(String url) {
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}
```